Injectivity and Surjectivity of 
$D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \lvert z \rvert <1 \}$ and $U=D-\{\pm\frac{1}{2}\}.$
$\mathscr{H}(D)$ is the set of complex valued holomorphic maps on $D$ and $\mathscr{H}\mathbb{B}(U)$ is the set of all complex valued holomorphic bounded maps on $U$ where the map $\gamma$ is given by
\begin{aligned}
   \gamma:\mathscr{H}(D) \rightarrow \mathscr{H}\mathbb{B}(U) \\
f\mapsto f|_U
\end{aligned}
Determine whether the map is injective, bijective or surjective.
My Approach
let $f\in \mathscr{H}\mathbb{B}(U) \implies$ $f$ is analytic on $U$ and bounded in the neighbourhood of $\pm \frac{1}{2}$; so at $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ $f$ has removable singularity, but I can' t think after that.
